# React Native PushNotification onNotification method

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am Getting notification from server. After receiving the notification, When I click on it, then again the same notification is coming. More I click on it more the notifications are coming.

My question is whether I am following the right approach in the above code? If not then please suggest me the correct one. How to handle the click of notification? So, that i can show the particular view on its click.

I'm using the following link
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Thanks in advance :)

```
PushNotification.configure({

      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification)
         PushNotification.localNotification({
          largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
          title: notification.title, 
          message: notification.message, 
        });

      },
      senderID: "my sender ID",
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
```

Comment: I think you should check if the notification is a remote notification or a local notification. Normally, If it is a remote notification then you dispatch a local notification, if it is a local notification, you interact with the user.

Comment: My problem is resolved with the help of answer suggested by Navneet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried the following approach to solve this problem

```
PushNotification.configure({

      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification)
        const clicked = notification.userInteraction;
        if (clicked) {
         ToastAndroid.show(notification.message,ToastAndroid.CENTER);
        } else {
          PushNotification.localNotification({
            largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
            title: "Test",
            //message: JSON.stringify(xyz.notificationResponse.bookingId), 
          });
        }
        ToastAndroid.show(notification.message,ToastAndroid.CENTER);
      },


      senderID: "your sender id",
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
```